# knockout arrayfirst not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js

I have a fiddle with a bunch of knockout code and bindings.  I have one binding that checks for an item in an observablearray and it seems to be always returning true, no matter what value I type in.  Put your cursor in the last input on the last row and tab out.  It will add a new row.  Now type a value into the first input and tab out.  It is supposed to check the existing observablearray and return true or false if it exists.  Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mf1wona9/6/

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="brochureItems">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Item No
        </th>
        <th>
            Bro Code
        </th>
        <th width="36%">
            Desc
        </th>
        <th width="15%">
            Retail
        </th>
        <th>
            Prize Cnt
        </th>
        <th>
            Order
        </th>
        <th>
            Remove
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div data-bind="if: ($index() === $parent.items().length-1)"><input data-bind="value: itemNo, hasFocus: $parent.invalidItem(), selected: $parent.invalidItem(), event: { blur: $parent.checkItemNo }, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control item-id" /></div>
            <div data-bind="ifnot: ($index() === $parent.items().length-1)"><input data-bind="value: itemNo, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control item-ID" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-bind="if: (brocCode.length < 1)">
                <input data-bind="value: brocCode, insertPress: $index, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].brocCode', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__brocCode' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div data-bind="if: (brocCode.length > 0)">
                <input data-bind="value: brocCode, insertPress: $index, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].brocCode', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__brocCode' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="item-desc">
            <input data-bind="value: itemDesc, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemDesc', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemDesc' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
        </td>
        <td class="item-retail">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                <div data-bind="if: ($index() === ($parent.items().length - 1))"><input data-bind="value: retail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].retail', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__retail' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, style: { backgroundColor: retail == 0 ? '#FFFCCE' : '#ffffff'}" class="form-control" /></div>
                <div data-bind="if: ($index() < ($parent.items().length - 1))"><input data-bind="value: retail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', money: retail, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].retail', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__retail' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, style: { backgroundColor: retail == 0 ? '#FFFCCE' : '#ffffff'}" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><input data-bind="value: prizeNum, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].prizeNum', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__prizeNum' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, style: { backgroundColor: prizeNum == 0 ? '#FFFCCE' : '#ffffff'}" class="form-control" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-bind="if: ($index() === ($parent.items().length - 1))"><input data-bind="value: itemOrder, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterPress: 'addRow', attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemOrder', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemOrder' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, style: { backgroundColor: itemOrder == 0 ? '#FFFCCE' : '#ffffff'}" class="form-control" /></div>
            <div data-bind="if: ($index() < ($parent.items().length - 1))"><input data-bind="value: itemOrder, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemOrder', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemOrder' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }, style: { backgroundColor: itemOrder == 0 ? '#FFFCCE' : '#ffffff'}" class="form-control" /></div>
        </td>
        <td class="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeRow" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Knockout:

```
var listOfItems;

ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
    ko.validation.init({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null,
        decorateInputElement: true,
    }, true);

    (function(){

        var toMoney = function(num){
            if(num != null && num != "") {
                num = parseFloat(num);
                return (num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,') );
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        };

        var handler = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings){
            var $el = $(element);
            var method;

            // Gives us the real value if it is a computed observable or not
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap( valueAccessor() );

            if($el.is(':input')){
                method = 'val';
            } else {
                method = 'text';
            }
            return $el[method]( toMoney( valueUnwrapped ) );
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.money = {
            update: handler
        };
    })();

    var itemModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.invalidItem = ko.observable(true);
        self.itemNo = ko.observable(data ? data.itemNo : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item no. required."
            }
        });
        self.brocCode = ko.observable(data ? data.brocCode : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Bro code required."
            }
        });
        self.itemDesc = ko.observable(data ? data.itemDesc : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item desc required."
            }
        });
        self.retail = ko.observable(data ? data.retail : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Retail required."
            }
        })
        .extend({numeric: 2});
        self.prizeNum = ko.observable(data ? data.prizeNum : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Prize num required."
            }
        });
        self.itemOrder = ko.observable(data ? data.itemOrder : '').extend( {
            required: {
                params: true,
                message: "Item order required."
            }
        });
    }

    var itemsModel = function(items) {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.mapping.fromJSON(items);

        self.invalidItem = ko.observable(true);

        self.checkItemNo = function(data) {
            console.log("lost focus - " + self.invalidItem());
            var itemNo = $.trim(data.itemNo());
            console.log(itemNo);
            if (itemNo != "") {
                var item = "";
                item = "Fusion";
                console.log(item);
                if(item != "") {
                    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(newItem) {
                        return itemNo === newItem.itemNo();
                    }).itemNo();
                    console.log("match: " + match);
                    if (!match) {
                        data.itemDesc(item);
                    } else { // item already entered
                        console.log("item already entered");
                      data.invalidItem(true);
                      setTimeout(function() { data.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
                      //data.itemDesc("");
                    }
                } else { // invalid item #
                    console.log("invalid item");
                    data.invalidItem(true);
                    setTimeout(function() { data.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
                    data.itemDesc("");
                }
            }
        }

        self.submit = function() {
            //self.showErrors(true);
            if (viewModel.errors().length === 0) {
                console.log('Thank you.');
                $("#brochureForm").submit();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Please check your submission.');
                viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                $(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
            }
        }

        self.addLine = function() {
            var iModel = new itemModel();
            iModel.invalidItem(true);
            self.invalidItem(true);
            console.log("adding new line; it is: " + self.invalidItem());
            self.items.push( iModel );
            //setTimeout(function() { self.invalidItem(true); }, 1);
        };

        self.insertLine = function(index) {
            self.items.splice(index, 0, new itemModel() );
        };

        self.removeItem = function(item) {
            self.items.remove(item);
        };

        self.errors = ko.validation.group(self.items, { deep: true, live: true });

        self.validate = function() {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    };

    var profitCode = function(code, desc, name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.name = name;
    };

    var codeModel = function(codes) {
        var self = this;
        self.availableProfitCodes = ko.observableArray([])
        self.codes = ko.observableArray(codes);
    }

    var profitItemsModel = function(items) {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    }

    var combined = (function () {
        function combinedVM() {
            this.codes = ko.observable(codeModel);
            this.items = ko.observable(profitItemsModel);
            this.availableProfitCodes = codeModel.availableProfitCodes;
        }
        return combinedVM;
    })();

    ko.bindingHandlers.enterPress = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            element.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
                if (keyCode === 13 || (!event.shiftKey && keyCode === 9)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //bindingContext.$root.invalidItem(false);
                    bindingContext.$root.addLine();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    };

        ko.bindingHandlers.insertPress = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
                element.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
                    var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
                    if (keyCode === 45) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        bindingContext.$root.insertLine(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            }
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.selected = {
            update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var selected = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                if (selected) element.select();
            }
        };        

        function GetItems() {
    var itemsJSON =  '[{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"1000","brocCode":"1000","itemDesc":"Bicycle","retail":13.5, "prizeNum":1, "itemOrder":1},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"1100","brocCode":"1100","itemDesc":"Front Wheel","retail":35, "prizeNum":2, "itemOrder":2},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"1120","brocCode":"1120","itemDesc":"Spokes","retail":12.5, "prizeNum":3, "itemOrder":3},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"1150","brocCode":"1150","itemDesc":"Front Hub","retail":5, "prizeNum":4, "itemOrder":4},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"1151","brocCode":"1151","itemDesc":"Axle Front Wheel","retail":14, "prizeNum":5, "itemOrder":5},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"120","brocCode":"120","itemDesc":"Loudspeaker, Black, 120W","retail":12.5, "prizeNum":6, "itemOrder":6},{"brochureId":1,"itemNo":"125","brocCode":"125","itemDesc":"Socket Back","retail":10, "prizeNum":7, "itemOrder":7}]';
    var viewModel = new itemsModel(itemsJSON);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#brochureItems")[0]);
  }

$(document).ready(function () {
    GetItems();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new item is part of the observable array. To check whether it matches some *other* item, you need to ensure that you are not comparing it to itself:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(newItem) {
    return data !== newItem && itemNo === newItem.itemNo();
});
```