# knockoutjs - checking if item exists in array always returns true

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table which is an observablearray of observable items.  The first item in each row is the item number.  I load my page with maybe 10 rows of existing data.  I try to add a new row of data.  I type in the item number and tab out.  When that happens it runs a check to see if it is already in the array or not so it won't let the user add multiple of the same item number.  Well, since it is observable, I am assuming it instantly gets added to the array as I type it in or maybe when I tab out.  So that check is ***always*** returning true.

Here is my function that does the checking:

```
self.checkItemNo = function(data) {
  //console.log("lost focus - " + self.invalidItem());
  var itemNo = $.trim(data.itemNo());
  console.log(itemNo);
  if (itemNo != "") {
    var item = "";
    $.each(window.listOfItems, function(i, v) {
    if (v.No.search(itemNo) != -1) {
      item = v.Description;
      return;
    }
  });
  console.log(item);

  if(item != "") {
    console.log(self.items()[0].itemNo());
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(oldItem) {
      console.log("checking " + newItem.itemNo());
      //return itemNo === newItem.itemNo();
      return newItem !== oldItem && newItem.itemNo() === oldItem.itemNo();
  });
```

And here is where checkItemNo gets called:

```
<input data-bind="value: itemNo, hasFocus: invalidItem, selected: invalidItem, event: { blur: $parent.checkItemNo }, attr: { name: 'brochureitems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control item-id" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are not comparing an item to itself. It's not clear where `itemNo` comes from; it should be a member of one of `self.items`. Also, your names are somewhat backward: `newItem` is really the existing item being compared.

So if the new item is `newItem`, your compare might look like:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(oldItem) {
  return newItem !== oldItem && newItem.itemNo() === oldItem.itemNo();
});
```

Comment: I added a bit more code for context.  What would newItem be in my case?

Comment: I answered your other version of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600623/knockout-arrayfirst-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for a duplicate, just trying to figure out this stuff asap.